# Auth0 retrieve new access token from refresh token

Tags: ios, swift, native, auth0, auth0-lock

I'm having some troubles trying to get a new access token from a refresh token. I'm using a native app with swift 4.

LoginController looks like

```
func checkAccessToken() {
        SessionManager.shared.refreshToken { error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                guard error == nil else {
                    print("Failed to renew credentials: \(String(describing: error))")
                    return self.showLock()
                }
                SessionManager.shared.retrieveProfile { error in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        guard error == nil else {
                            print("Failed to retrieve profile: \(String(describing: error))")
                            return self.showLock()
                        }
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "HomeView", sender: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

SessionManager looks like:

```
func refreshToken(_ callback: @escaping (Error?) -> ()) {
        guard let refreshToken = self.keychain.string(forKey: self.keyRefresh) else {
            return callback(SessionManagerError.noRefreshToken)
        }

        Auth0
            .authentication()
            .renew(withRefreshToken: refreshToken)
            .start { result in
                switch (result) {
                case .success(let credentials):
                    self.storeTokens(credentials.accessToken)
                    callback(nil)
                case .failure(let error):
                    self.logout()
                    callback(error)
                }
            }
    }
```

and retrieveProfile:

```
func retrieveProfile(_ callback: @escaping (Error?) -> ()) {
    guard let accessToken = self.keychain.string(forKey: self.keyAccessToken) else {
        return callback(SessionManagerError.noAccessToken)
    }

    Auth0
        .authentication()
        .userInfo(token: accessToken)
        .start { result in
            switch(result) {
            case .success(let profile):
                self.profile = profile
                callback(nil)
            case .failure(let error):
                callback(error)
            }
    }
}
```

The *refreshToken* returns true. So, in theory, access token is new.
Then I'm trying to retrieve profile again with the new access token and the result of *RetrieveProfile* is an error with:

`Failed to retrieve profile: Optional({"sub":"****","email":"*****@gmail.com","email_verified":true})`
Status Code is 0